# Condense cumbersome Apache "allow from" directive

Tags: apache-2.2

```
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from cdn1.domain.com cdn2.domain.com cdn3.domain.com cdn4.domain.com cdn5.domain.com
</Proxy>
```

It's actually much longer than that. Is it possible to use regex somehow? I'm running 2.2

Comment: What IP range(s) are the CDN servers on?

Comment: @EightBitTony Hardcoding the IP range is asking for problems down the line

Comment: Unfortunately, they are all on various different subnets.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy with proper configuration management, it's no harder to update some IP addresses than it is some hostnames.  If all your CDN servers are always in 192.168.1/24 then using a range is better than individual hostnames, etc.  Without knowing the information, you can't provide a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can allow all hosts in `domain.com`, then it's pretty simple:

```
Allow from .domain.com
```

If you need to allow just those `cdn*` hosts, then you're out of luck - regex is not supported in `Allow` and other access control mechanisms aren't capable of doing the necessary reverse DNS lookup (like `mod_rewrite` or `SetEnvIf` with `Allow from env=`).

As EightBitTony mentioned in the comment, you'd need to use some other criteria to control access -- IP range would be the best.

**Edit:** Actually, `mod_rewrite` might be capable with the `REMOTE_HOST` variable.  Maybe try something like this?  Not sure if it does the reverse lookup and forward lookup to confirm, so the security might not be as reliable.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^cdn\d+\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [E:CDNALLOW]
Allow from env=CDNALLOW
```

Comment: forward lookup is not a worry, unless my httpd.conf file is leaked, it would be a good case of security through obscurity, thanks for the idea

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for the [allow](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) directive is quite good, it says allow will accept a partial name so

```
Allow from domain.com
```

Would simplify it somewhat as long as you don't mind the rest of domain.com accessing the proxy, there are also caveats regarding the forward/reverse DNS lookups for the hosts.

If the cdn machines share subnets or partial subnets you may be able to do something with that too.

Comment: I don't want "domain.com"  I would need something like "cdn[0-9]+.domain.com"

Comment: @Moonstone: You can't do that.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, the docs of course can only implicitly confirm that

Answer (score 2):

1) If anything under domain.com is OK, you could use a leading dot ( ie, .domain.com )

2) You could populate an environment variable and have Apache reference that.

```
allow from env=allowed_cdn_hosts
```